# Как сделать подсказку при нажатии ПКМ на рабочем столе? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Собственно суть вопроса в заголовке, как сделать подсказку при нажатии ПКМ на рабочем столе?
Я сделал приложение, по типу FileSharing'a, которое отправляет файл на сервер, но не удобно заходить каждый раз в приложение и выбирать файл для отправки, хочется иметь функционал, что бы выделил файл и через ПКМ отправил файл[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [гляньте это](https://coderoad.ru/18309300/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-Windows-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%9C%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8)

Comment: не относится к C#, по идее, если мне память не изменяет, там реестр надо подправить

Comment: @KuzCode негоже давать здесь ссылки на зеркала https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309300/how-to-add-a-menu-item-in-windows-right-click-menu

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Создайте в реестре директорию:   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\Отправить через мою программу`
В ней директорию:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\Отправить через мою программу\command`
В параметр по-умолчанию в директории `command` установите значение:
`cmd /c C:\путь к папке программы\имя программы.exe "передаваемые параметры без кавычек если они нужны" "%1"`
Примеры:
`cmd /c C:\myapp\myapp.exe -param1=one -param2=two "%1"`
`cmd /c C:\myapp\myapp.exe "%1"`
Где `%1` - путь к файлу на который вы кликнули.

После перезапуска explorer (который может не потребоваться) - при нажатии ПКМ на любой файл, одним из верхних пунктов будет тот пункт меню, который вы создали.